# Can a non-negative function, zero on the rationals, have a positive integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

Take a function $cos^2(x)$. It has zeros at $\pi/2 + {\pi}\cdot n$. Then consider the function 
$$f(x) = (cos^2(x))^{1/x^2}$$
At $x>0$ it also has zeros at $\pi/2 + {\pi}\cdot n$, but as $x \to \infty$, $f(x)$ becomes almost indistinguishable from 1:
$$\int_0^{\infty}(1-f(x))dx = const$$

Now, take the x at interval $[\pi/2, \pi/2 + \pi)$, map it to $[0, 1)$, and on $[0, 1)$ define $g_1(x) = f(\pi/2 + \pi{\cdot}x)$.

Then take an adjacent interval $[\pi/2 + \pi, \pi/2 + 3\pi)$ on which $f(x)$ has zero at $\pi/2 + 2\pi$, map it again at $[0, 1)$ to get $g_2(x)$, and introduce $h_2(x) = g_1(x)\cdot{h_1}(x)$, where $h_1(x) = g_1(x)$.

Repeat this process $n$ times to get $h_n(x) = g_{n-1}(x){\cdot}h_{n-1}(x)$, where each $g_{n}$ is produced by mapping $f(x)$ from the interval which starts at the end of the previous interval, and has length $n\pi$, i.e. the $n$-th interval is $$\left[\frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{{\pi}n(n-1)}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{{\pi}n(n-1)}{2} + n\pi\right)$$

Then consider an integral:

$$I_n = \int_0^1{h_n(x)dx} $$

The question is: can it be proven that $\lim_{n\to\infty}{I_n} > 0$ ?

Comment: The question in your title is not the same as what you are asking. Indeed, the answer to the question in your title is very easy (answer is YES), for example the function equal to 1 when $x = \sqrt{2}$ and equal to $0$ everywhere else.

Comment: Yes, by "non zero" I actually mean a function which is a) non-negative, and b) has non-zero integral (0,1). Thought it would be too verbose though.

Comment: I just saw you comment and revised your title in a way that's not much longer than it originally was. Feel free to modify (or undo) what I've done if you wish.